# Access profile images of the people from their twitter account in Android

Tags: android, twitter

I have Android application, which have directory module and it list out some of the contacts. Now I want to fetch `profile image` of each contact person from their `Twitter account` and for that I have their `twitter username` too. How I can fetch it in Android?

I have already tried with this but getting no success.

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(readDrawableFromNetwork("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=twitterapi&size=bigger"));
```

Comment: I am not sure if I have to use Json parsing. Will it fix the issue?

Comment: if we use json parsing instead of direct url we can get profile image. if use direct url like i don't know how to get;

Comment: Do you have any link on Json parsing and which is related to my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the relavent API for twitter [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline)  we can get json from this , by using json string we can do what ever you want. for profile image use this json object : profile_image_url you can get iamge url. by using url get image drawable.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code and it is working now

```
String twitterURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=#screen_name#&size=normal";
twitterURL = twitterURL.replace("#screen_name#", twitterScreenName);
imageView.setImageDrawable(readDrawableFromNetwork(twitterURL));
```

I also tried with below code and it is also working but I am not sure which one is best for the performance and recommended too.

```
URL urlImg = new URL(twitterURL);
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlImg.openStream());
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Thanks RajaReddy P :)